# ForEachAsync and adding items to collection which is outside - list or a concurrency collection?

Tags: c#

Should I use list or a concurrency collection If I use ForEachAsync in below code?

```
var images = new List<Image>(); // or a concurrency collection?
await users.ForEachAsync(async u =>
{
    Image image = await DownloadImageAsync(u.ImageId);
    images.Add(image);
});
```

Comment: But DownloadImageAsync returns a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
// Create a list of tasks
var imageTasks = new List<Task<Image>>();

// Use ForEachAsync to add tasks to the list
await users.ForEachAsync(u => imageTasks.Add(DownloadImageAsync(u.ImageId)));

// Wait for all tasks to complete
IEnumerable<Image> images = await Task.WhenAll(imageTasks);
```

The problem with using `ForEachAsync` the way you have, is that it accepts an `Action<T>` which cannot be awaited. This means that `ForEachAync` will likely complete before all `DownloadImageAsync` calls have completed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this concurrently, instead of using an intermediate collection, you can also project out the `DownloadImageAsynctasks` using `.Select` and then await the final result, i.e.

```
var images = await Task.WhenAll(users.Select(u => DownloadImageAsync(u.ImageId)));
```

You do need to be somewhat careful of the number of items in the collection when using this technique, however. This can place a lot of load on the downstream I/O bound systems (you might be throttled), and after completion of each download, a thread will be briefly be needed for each task in order to collect each result into the final collection.